# GREP AND AWK file with IP and Ports

Tags: awk, grep

I need some assistance I have a file that has Host IPs and Ports each on their column, so the file looks like this

```
Timestamp: 1573678793 Host: 192.168.0.1 Ports: 80/open/tcp/
Timestamp: 1574833457 Host: 192.168.0.1 Ports: 443/open/tcp/
Timestamp: 1574833457 Host: 192.168.0.2 Ports: 80/open/tcp/
Timestamp: 1574833457 Host: 192.168.0.2 Ports: 443/open/tcp/
Timestamp: 1574833457 Host: 192.168.0.3 Ports: 8080/open/tcp/
```

So I want to grep the host and ports in this format:

```
192.168.0.1  80,443
192.168.0.2  80,443
192.168.0.3  8080
```

Anyone who knows how this can be achieved with awk and grep, kindly also explain the syntax for me to understand, Thanks in advance.

What I have tried;

1. Getting the host and ports on different files and then use the paste command to paste them in a new file, but the issue with that is that the ip's are repeating with different ports and I would love to make the data clean.
2. I have googled and found some command that does that: `cat ips-ports | | grep Host | awk '{print $2,$7}' | sed 's@/.*@@' | sort -t' ' -n -k2 | awk -F' ' -v OFS=' ' '{x=$1;$1="";a[x]=a[x]","$0}END{for(x in a) print x,a[x]}' | sed 's/, /,/g' | sed 's/ ,/ /' | sort -V -k1 | cut -d " " -f2`

But I would love to understand what it does because on my file it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problem, so kindly do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: Sure, please add these details in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Ok np, we all learn. But whatever you have tried please post them in your question NOT in comments, cheers.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Sorry about that, was adding the few things I have done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
{
  match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/)
  split($NF,array,"/")
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  a[val]=(a[val]?a[val] OFS:"")array[1]
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    print i FS a[i]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                              ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                             ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  OFS=","                                          ##Set OFS as comma here.
}                                                  ##Closing BLOCK for BEGIN section here.
{
  match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/)       ##Using match function ti match IP regex here.
  split($NF,array,"/")                             ##Splitting last field into an array named array with delimiter /
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)                    ##Creating a variable named val whose value is sub-string of line with starting point RSTART to RLENGTH.
  a[val]=(a[val]?a[val] OFS:"")array[1]            ##Creating an array named a with index val and concatenate it with its own values.
}
END{                                               ##Starting END BLOCK for this awk program.
  for(i in a){                                     ##Starting for loop here.
    print i FS a[i]                                ##Printing variable i, FS and value of array a with index i here.
  }                                                ##Closing BLOCK for, for loop here.
}                                                  ##Closing BLOCK for END section of this program here.
'  Input_file                                      ##Mentioning Input_file here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Some more `awk`

**Output:**

```
$ awk -F '[ /]' '{arr[$4]=$4 in arr?arr[$4]","$6:$6}END{for(i in arr)print i,arr[i]}' infile
192.168.0.1 80,443
192.168.0.2 80,443
192.168.0.3 8080
```

**Input:**

```
$ cat infile
Timestamp: 1573678793 Host: 192.168.0.1 Ports: 80/open/tcp/
Timestamp: 1574833457 Host: 192.168.0.1 Ports: 443/open/tcp/
Timestamp: 1574833457 Host: 192.168.0.2 Ports: 80/open/tcp/
Timestamp: 1574833457 Host: 192.168.0.2 Ports: 443/open/tcp/
Timestamp: 1574833457 Host: 192.168.0.3 Ports: 8080/open/tcp/
```

**Better Readable version:**

```
awk -F '[ /]' '{
                arr[$4] = $4 in arr ? arr[$4] "," $6 : $6
              }
           END{
                for(i in arr)
                   print i,arr[i]
              }' infile
```

Comment: @n00b just cross check input file you showed here is matching your original input, `F '[ /]'` uses either space or forward slash as column separator while reading file, execute `awk -F '[ /]'  '{ print $4, $6}' infile`, if its printing ip and port properly it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Following short pipeline with `sed` and `awk`:

```
# first `sed` with a regex extract the host and ports:
sed 's/.*Host:[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]*\)[[:blank:]]*Ports:[[:blank:]]*\([0-9]*\)\/.*/\1 \2/' |
# then awk to join the fields with a comma:
awk '{ a[$1] = a[$1] (a[$1]?",":"") $2 }  END{ for (i in a) print i, a[i] }'
```

with the following input:

```
Timestamp: 1573678793 Host: 192.168.0.1 Ports: 80/open/tcp/
Timestamp: 1574833457 Host: 192.168.0.1 Ports: 443/open/tcp/
Timestamp: 1574833457 Host: 192.168.0.2 Ports: 80/open/tcp/
Timestamp: 1574833457 Host: 192.168.0.2 Ports: 443/open/tcp/
Timestamp: 1574833457 Host: 192.168.0.3 Ports: 8080/open/tcp/
```

outputs:

```
192.168.0.1 80,443
192.168.0.2 80,443
192.168.0.3 8080
```

Tested on [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/SqueakySameEditors).

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work, it prints the timestamp

Comment: I guess maybe you have a file with tabs, not with spaces.

Comment: Yeah the file has tabs not spaces